# Why I can't import/export collada (.dae) files?

Tags: collada

That's the way it looks at me:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

And it should look like:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Xubuntu v16.04 Blender v2.76 (also tried 2.78 from launchpad).

Comment: You have to enable the Collada addon in the user preferences. Go to *File > User Preferences > Addons* and search for Collada.

Comment: Grab a blender version from [here](https://www.blender.org/download/) and it is enabled by default.

Comment: Versions from ubuntu repositories don't have this addon, but official release has. Thank you very much! Answer please that I could close the issue.